# How to rotate object in a scene with pan gesture - SceneKit

Tags: swift, rotation, scenekit

I'm tying to create an app with Scene kit to solve Rubix Cube. I've my own dae file for the cube.
this is my setup code in viewDidLoad

```
    let myscene = SCNScene(named: "Rubik1.scnassets/Rubiks_Cube.dae")
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode((myscene?.rootNode)!)

    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene

    geometryNode = (scnView.scene?.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Cube",recursively: true))!

    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panGesture:")
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)
```

upon recognising a pan gesture to rotate the cube

```
func panGesture(gestureRecognize: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    let translation = gestureRecognize.translationInView(gestureRecognize.view!)

    let x = Float(translation.x)
    let y = Float(-translation.y)

    let anglePan = sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2))*(Float)(M_PI)/180.0

    var rotationVector = SCNVector4()
    rotationVector.x = -y
    rotationVector.y = x
    rotationVector.z = 0
    rotationVector.w = anglePan

    geometryNode.rotation = rotationVector

    //geometryNode.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(anglePan, -y, x, 0)

    if(gestureRecognize.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        //
    }
}
```

above code doesn't preserve the previous pan gestures. how do I use "rotationvector" or

```
SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(anglePan, -y, x, 0)
```

to rotate the cube

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is solved

```
if(gestureRecognize.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {

    let currentPivot = geometryNode.pivot
    let changePivot = SCNMatrix4Invert( geometryNode.transform)

    geometryNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4Mult(changePivot, currentPivot)

    geometryNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity
}
```

Comment: Only working if the transform position of the original object is at (0,0,0) though.

Comment: Throughout the life of the application, the object will be at 0,0,0. This solves my need and is just enough for the time being.

Answer (score 7):

This solution works if your object original position isn't (0,0,0).

```
    if(gestureRecognize.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
       let currentPivot = geometryNode.pivot
       let currentPosition = geometryNode.position
       let changePivot = SCNMatrix4Invert(SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(geometryNode.rotation.w, geometryNode.rotation.x, geometryNode.rotation.y, geometryNode.rotation.z))

       geometryNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4Mult(changePivot, currentPivot)
       geometryNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity
       geometryNode.position = currentPosition
    }
```

But I don't understand why we assign the invert value of transform or rotation to changePivot. Is it correct, we are trying to rotate the pivot to our current rotation values and with setting the .transform property to the identity matrix it resets the node to the pivot value. We don't see any change, because the pivot already has the same values as our node right then. 
But why we use the invert values, normally you use this to rotate something back to its origin. Can somebody tell me, where i'm thinking wrong?

Comment: The question has already been answered and your answer brings nothing new.

Comment: The answer only works if position of the original object is at (0,0,0). My answer is just an addition and it works even if the orignial position is for example (0,0,-1). I tried to comment, but didn't have enough points...

Comment: The object translates a bit while using this logic. Rotation works all right, but the translation is a concern. Probably because my initial transform itself is not an identity matrix. Translation happens for the first time gesture ends and doesn't happen anymore. Any idea?

Comment: @Manganese I expected for the input to be a swipe of a finger and also to be an instantaneous/short swipe. So it was my intention to rotate when the gesture ends and stop so that, user can chose to rotate another or same side