# Axes rotate with SCNNode

Tags: rotation, scenekit, axes, scnsphere

If I rotate a sphere around the x-axis 90degree, the axes rotate with it. So the y-axis which is vertical first has now the position of the z-axis at the start.

I want my axes fixed, so that if i rotate around x-axis (1,0,0) it always rotates from front/back and around y-axis (0,1,0) from left/right.

Do I therefore have to calculate it with normals? Inputs appreciated.

Comment: hi @Franhu, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194914/how-to-rotate-object-in-a-scene-with-pan-gesture-scenekit/45947211#45947211