# I have added a Human 3d Model in Scene Kit , its background is black how to make it as white as front view?

Tags: ios, swift, scene

I have added a Human 3d Model in Scene Kit. Its background is black how to make it as white as front view? I have used this in swift app, used scene kit and human 3d model, Please check image I have attached..

#### Back View

[image]

#### 3d Model Settings

[image]

Code :-

```
 //MARK: - Scene Related Methods
func loadScene() {
    self.removeExistingNodes()
    loadSceneLayer(fileName: "FinalBaseMesh.obj")
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = false
    
    load3DScene()
    
    //layerSelectionIndex = 0
    sceneView.scene = scene
}

func load3DScene() {
    sceneView.scene = scene
    // Allow user to manipulate camera
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    
    sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = true
    sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.panSensitivity = 0.9
    
    sceneView.delegate = self as SCNSceneRendererDelegate
    //            sceneView.isPlaying = true
    for reco in sceneView.gestureRecognizers! {
        if let panReco = reco as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            panReco.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
        }
    }
    
    //         add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleTap(_:)))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    
    self.addSavedNode()
    
}



func loadSceneLayer(fileName: String) {
    
    
    scene = SCNScene(named: fileName) ?? SCNScene()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    
    
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 6.5, z: 20)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light?.type = .omni
    
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 6.5, z: 20)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    
    // 6: Creating and adding ambien light to scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light?.type = .ambient
    ambientLightNode.light?.color = UIColor.darkGray
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
    
}
```

I forgot to add last method please check loadstonelayer method

Comment: It helps us to see the code -- it looks like a lighting issue -- you are rotating the entire scene including the lights and there are no lights on the back.  One way to fix is to just rotate the human and leave the lighting in place, but we need to see code

Comment: is there any way to rotate the model without the light ? I mean light stays where it is and we can only rotate the model so that when back side of the body comes at the place of front side it will be shown us as front body was..

Comment: Get rid of your camera control code and see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194914/how-to-rotate-object-in-a-scene-with-pan-gesture-scenekit

Comment: This code isn't worked for me , it shows total black 3d model.

Comment: Hello @louFranco This issue is solved , I have added 
in Light node and issue is solved by setting z = -20

Comment: I put in an answer summarizing the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove all the camera control code
2. See [How to rotate object in a scene with pan gesture - SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194914/how-to-rotate-object-in-a-scene-with-pan-gesture-scenekit) for rotating an object
3. Put in a light node at a negative z facing the object